# Regex Explanation required

Tags: javascript, regex

My Regex:

```
\d{0,2}\.?\d{0,3}r?em
```

string to match:

```
12123rem
```

Why is it matching 5 digits?

I want it to match the following pattern only:
12em or 12 rem or 12.345em or 12.345rem

up to 3 decimal places only.

Comment: 2 digits + 3 digits = 5 digits. The dot is optional.

Comment: You probably want to make the decimal part optional: `(?:\.\d{0,3})?`

Comment: @adiga It's excepting this also "12.rem". regex: \d{0,2}(?:\.\d{0,3})rem

Comment: @SushmitSagar you missed the `?` I added at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,3})?\s?r?em$
```

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hh6NzW/1)

- `^` - assures we are at the begining of the string
- `^\d{0,2}` zero up to two decimals after begining of string
- `(\.\d{1,3})` optional group of 1 up to 3 digits with `.` in front
- `\s?` optional whitespace character
- `r?` optional `r` character
- `em` mandatory `em`
- `$` end of the string

Comment: this also matches "12.rem". the decimal must be not be without digits after it.

Comment: @Sushmit Sagar I thought that what you wanted, since I did not change this part of regex. Anyway - I've jest corrected it.

Comment: if there's decmial then there must be digits it cant. be "12."

Comment: fixed it, check it out.

Comment: do you want to match also .345rem? If not change ```^\d{0,2}``` to ```^\d{1,2}``` Note it won't accept any number with more than 2 digits before dot (i.e 101.01rem).